# Correct ffmpeg scale command syntax

Tags: php, ffmpeg, scale

I am new to ffmpeg and need some help with the correct syntax for a scale command I found [here](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-December/003656.html).

Below is my code:

```
$width=300;
$height=200;
$aspect=$width/$height;


$command = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -i 1.mp4 -vf scale=min(1\,gt(iw\,".$width.")+gt(ih\,".$height.")) * (gte(a\,".$aspect.")*".$width." + \
lt(a\,".$aspect.")*((".$height."*iw)/ih)) + not(min(1\,gt(iw\,".$width.")+gt(ih\,".$height.")))*iw : \
min(1\,gt(iw\,".$width.")+gt(ih\,".$height.")) * (lte(a\,".$aspect.")*".$height." + \
gt(a\,".$aspect.")*((".$width."*ih)/iw)) + not(min(1\,gt(iw\,".$width.")+gt(ih\,".$height.")))*ih  -b 1200k -acodec aac -strict -2 2.mp4 ";
```

Video is successfully converted however, the scaling does not go trough.

The code is copied word for word, I only make two changes:

- removed the " before `scale` word and from the end
- replaced the $FW with $width, $FH with $height and $FA with $aspect.

Any suggestion at what might be wrong?

Comment: Put the quotes back with `\"` or see the two non-accepted answers from http://superuser.com/questions/566998/how-can-i-fit-a-video-to-a-certain-size-but-dont-upscale-it-with-ffmpeg

Comment: Thanks mate, I suspected there was something wrong with the double quotes!